# How to integrate trading-vue-js in a vue cli project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I would like to use / integrate [trading-vue-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trading-vue-js). I can run trading-vue-js test examples just fine.

So, I did the following.

nmp install trading-vue-js

I've set up a vue, "views/Chart.vue" which loads fine.

But in attempting to follow the example code from trading-vue-js and add it to "views/chart.vue", no chart comes up.

```
<template>
  <div class="chartPage">
    <h1>This is a Trading Chart page</h1>
  </div>
<trading-vue :data="chart"
  :width="this.width"
  :height="this.height"
  :toolbar="true"
  :color-back="colors.colorBack"
  :color-grid="colors.colorGrid"
  :color-text="colors.colorText">
</trading-vue>
</template>

<script>
import { TradingVue, DataCube } from 'trading-vue-js'
import Data from 'data/data_btc.json'

export default {
  name: 'Simple',
  description: 'Should display everything okay',
  props: ['night'],
  components: {
    TradingVue
  },
  methods: {
    onResize (event) {
      this.width = window.innerWidth
      this.height = window.innerHeight - 50
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
    this.onResize()
    window.dc = this.chart
  },
  computed: {
    colors () {
      return this.$props.night ? {} : {
        colorBack: '#fff',
        colorGrid: '#eee',
        colorText: '#333'
      }
    }
  },
  beforeUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
  },
  data () {
    return {
      chart: new DataCube(Data),
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I have no errors returned.
In case you're wondering, I set up a path alias in vue.config.js so I can import the price data for the chart. The data is copied from the example files.

```
import Data from 'data/data_btc.json'
```

this seems to work because I'm seeing no errors.

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trading-vue-js) says

> Data structure
> PRO TIP: chart is mandatory if you want to see something other than a white screen

I think I've understood this to mean that `data(){}` requires at least the following:

```
    data () {
    return {
      chart: new DataCube(Data),
    }
```

which I've provided, but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I had made a mess of the naming of various components as well as bringing in various bits of code that were not necessary. I guess that’s what you get when you attempt to hack bits of code together when you don’t really understand what is going on.

I did a bit more RTFM. Then I created a visual diagram of how the blocks of code fitted together, which helped me compare the working test examples vs my own code. That’s how I eventually identified what I had done wrong.

So I stripped it back to the most simple configuration. Bingo! It worked.

Installing the Vue Developer extension for Firefox was also of great assistance.